# Log in at checkout doesnt work

Tags: onepage-checkout, login

When going through my check out if the customer is already a customer and tried to log in on my checkout page, when you click log in it just take you to the accounts log in page and i dont understand why. I tried adding the form key line as i have seen this has fixed other peoples problems but no luck.

```
<div class="block block-checkout-login">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">

        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
        <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('Already registered?') ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Please log in below:') ?></p>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <li>
                        <label for="login-email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="login-password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry" id="login-password" name="login[password]" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                </ul>
                <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>

        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    $('login-email').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
    $('login-password').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
    function bindLoginPost(evt){
        if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
            loginForm.submit();
        }
    }
    function onepageLogin(button)
    {
        if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
            button.disabled = true;
            loginForm.submit();
        }
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

thank you so much if you can help

Comment: is it standard magento checkout or any custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Magento 1.8 you need to post a formKey with your login information.

After

```
<ul class="form-list">
```

add the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

You're also going to want to check your login forms at template/customer/form/login.phtml and template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: Thank you it logs the user in now. but it doesnt go to the next checkout page it re-directs to the accounts page..